# Why are some Prelude functions defined in terms of foldl?

Tags: built-in, haskell

Generally, `foldl` is avoided in favor of `foldl'` or `foldr`. Quoting [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html):

> Due to the thunking behavior of foldl, it is wise to avoid this
>   function in real programs: even if it doesn't fail outright, it will
>   be unnecessarily inefficient. Instead, import Data.List and use
>   foldl'.

Yet some Prelude functions are defined in terms of it (e.g. [`(\\)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#%5C%5C) and [`unionBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#unionBy)). Why is this? Is it to not introduce too much strictness to these functions?

Comment: Note: strictness analysis in GHC means that `foldl` works out better than you would think suprisingly often.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `(\\)` and `unionBy` are not in Prelude.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Prelude was designed before `foldl'` existed, and there's been pressure to maintain backwards compatibility (with regards to strictness, as you mentioned) since then.

Comment: That's interesting. So does the advice of not using `foldl` propagate? I mean, should we avoid `(\\)` and `unionBy` too?

Comment: @Tarrasch Often, yep, especially with the numeric folds. It's pretty common to implement `sum' = foldl' (+) 0` and such things in each project that needs them.

Comment: @DanielWagner: actually, `sum` isn't defined in terms of `foldl` except for `USE_REPORT_PRELUDE`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#sum

Comment: @amindfv While that's true, the implementation given is just as lazy as `foldl` -- and that's the problem.

Answer (score 10):

In the case of `(\\)` and `unionBy`, the folded function has type

```
foo :: [a] -> b -> [a]
```

and `foo xs y` removes at most one element from `xs`, so using `foldl'` would not buy anything there in general, the thunks would be built on the right of the topmost `(:)` instead of above it then.

It would not make a difference in terms of strictness, as far as I can see, both folds would only be evaluated when the result needs to be evaluated to weak head normal form, and whenever `foldl'` would produce a `_|_`, so would `foldl`.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases the accumulator is of type `[a]`. I can't see that forcing the list to weak-head normal form would make a huge difference, and introducing such partial strictness seems somewhat arbitrary.